# In Chisel3, what imports do I need for the Printable examples?

Tags: chisel

I am trying to follow the example here:
https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/wiki/Printing-in-Chisel#custom-printing

As in the example, I overrode `def toPrintable: Printable` with a concatenation of `p"..." +` strings.

In my scala file I

```
import chisel3._
```

But I get Scala compile warnings that it doesn't know what `Printable` is nor does it know what to do with the `p` interpolator, which makes me think I don't have the right imports.

Is there something I need to import other than chisel3._?

Here is a bit more information on what I am doing and what error I am getting.
I am modifying this file:
https://github.com/chipsalliance/rocket-chip/blob/e6a6c67f30d668e702ddbef93789e9b4f709b237/src/main/scala/tilelink/Bundles.scala

Here is what I have added:

```
...
import Chisel._
import chisel3.{Printable}
...

final class TLBundleA(params: TLBundleParameters)
  extends TLBundleBase(params) with TLAddrChannel
{
  ...

  override def toPrintable: Printable = {
    p"A:\t" +
    p"opcode[${opcode}]\t" +
    p"param[${param}]\t" +
    p"size[${size}]\t" +
    p"source[${source}]\t" +
    p"address[${address}]\t" +
    p"user[${user}]\t" +
    p"mask[${mask}]\t" +
    p"data[${data}]\t" +
    p"corrupt[${corrupt}]\n"
  }
}
```

It seems that (unlike `import chisel3._`),  `import.chisel3.{Printable}` works, but I am not doing something right with the `p"..."`. I get this series of error:

```
[error] rocket-chip/src/main/scala/tilelink/Bundles.scala:189:5: value p is not a member of StringContext
[error]     p"A:\t" +
[error]     ^
[error] rocket-chip/src/main/scala/tilelink/Bundles.scala:190:5: value p is not a member of StringContext
[error]     p"opcode[${opcode}]\t" +
[error]     ^
...
[error] rocket-chip/src/main/scala/tilelink/Bundles.scala:198:5: value p is not a member of StringContext
[error]     p"corrupt[${corrupt}]\n"
[error]     ^
[error] 10 errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

EDIT TO UPDATE:
After looking at the Chisel3 source, I added 
`import chisel3.{Printable, PrintableHelper}` 
and now I get a new error which looks more like I am just messing up my string:

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
[error]     at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:268)
[error]     at chisel3.printf$.escaped$1(Printf.scala:28)
[error]     at chisel3.printf$.$anonfun$format$3(Printf.scala:32)
[error] ocketchiat chisel3.printf$.$anonfun$format$3$adapted(Printf.scala:32)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
[error]     at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
[error]     at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.foreach(StringOps.scala:33)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.map(StringOps.scala:33)
[error]     at chisel3.printf$.format(Printf.scala:32)
[error]     at chisel3.internal.firrtl.Emitter.emit(Emitter.scala:75)
[error]     at chisel3.internal.firrtl.Emitter.$anonfun$moduleDefn$4(Emitter.scala:140)
```

EDIT TO UPDATE:
I added more verbosity to the requires in the `printf` code and I think it doesn't like tabs (`\t`):

```
[error] (run-main-0) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: char    to Int 9 must be >= 32
[error] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: char     to Int 9 must be >= 32
```

EDIT TO UPDATE:

I modified `chisel3` to be OK with tabs, and now the code compiles and runs, but this is one of the resulting verilog strings which is obviously not right. I tried the string2Printable import you suggested but still get the following:

```
freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.v:          $fwrite(32'h80000002,"PLIC_TL_IFC A:\tPrintables(ArrayBuffer(PString(opcode[), Decimal(UInt<3>(IO in unelaborated TLMonitor)), PString(]\t)))Printables(ArrayBuffer(PString(param[), Decimal(UInt<3>(IO in unelaborated TLMonitor)), PString(]\t)))Printables(ArrayBuffer(PString(size[), Decimal(UInt<2>(IO in unelaborated TLMonitor)), PString(]\t)))Printables(ArrayBuffer(PString(source[), Decimal(UInt<9>(IO in unelaborated TLMonitor)), PString(]\t)))Printables(ArrayBuffer(PString(address[), Decimal(UInt<28>(IO in unelaborated TLMonitor)), PString(]\t)))Printables(ArrayBuffer(PString(user[), PString(None), PString(]\t)))Printables(ArrayBuffer(PString(mask[), Decimal(UInt<8>(IO in unelaborated TLMonitor)), PString(]\t)))Printables(ArrayBuffer(PString(data[), Decimal(UInt<64>(IO in unelaborated TLMonitor)), PString(]\t)))Printables(ArrayBuffer(PString(corrupt[), Decimal(Bool(IO in unelaborated TLMonitor)), PString(]\n)))"); // @[Monitor.scala 577:40:freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.fir@64082.10]

freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.v:          $fwrite(32'h80000002,"PLIC_TL_IFC TLBundleD(opcode -> %d, param -> %d, size -> %d, source -> %d, sink -> %d, denied -> %d, data -> %d, corrupt -> %d)",io_in_d_bits_opcode,2'h0,io_in_d_bits_size,io_in_d_bits_source,1'h0,1'h0,io_in_d_bits_data,1'h0); // @[Monitor.scala 578:40:freechips.rocketchip.system.DefaultConfig.fir@64090.10]
```

For reference, here is the callsite where I am actually calling this:

```
        when (bundle.a.fire()) { printf(p"$prefix ${bundle.a.bits}")}
        when (bundle.d.fire()) { printf(p"$prefix ${bundle.d.bits}")}
```

Note the `bundle.d.bits` looks "okay" because I haven't given it a specific toPrintable function, but `bundle.a.bits` is a mess.

EDIT: RESOLVED

The problem is I had changed my toPrintable in the course of debugging to be of the form

```
  override def toPrintable: Printable = {
    "A:\t" +
    p"opcode[$opcode]\t" +
    ...
    p"corrupt[$corrupt]\n"
  }
}
```

The first un-`p` string was making the rest of them just be normal strings, ignoring the `p`. I put the first `p"A:\t"` back and now it interpolates correctly.

Comment: As Chick said, this should work. Can you share more about your environment? What version of chisel3 are you using?

Comment: I've updated a bit more detail, thanks for following up.

Comment: I see, so it'll be a little ugly but custom string interpolators (like `p"..."`) are implemented using `implicits`. You can explicitly import the implicit: `import chisel3.PrintableHelper`, you should probably also `import chisel3.string2Printable`, although that one may not be necessary

Comment: Also this is the version of chisel I am using: `* 060b421 - (13 days ago) Fixed code example typo in comment (#1294) (#1313) - mergify[bot] (origin/3.2.x)`

Answer (score 0):

The `import chisel3._` should be enough. Try looking at the examples in the Chisel3 repo such as [LFSR16.scala](https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/blob/master/src/test/scala/chiselTests/LFSR16.scala). If that doesn't help can you show the error message.